# Wheres the global error handler in Xamarin Monotouch?

Tags: error-handling, xamarin.ios, xamarin

How do I implement a global handler in C# as mentioned here:

[How do you implement global iPhone Exception Handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282364/how-do-you-implement-global-iphone-exception-handling)

I'm trying to catch all errors so it can be logged and possibly uploaded to my server as a crash report.  I was initially thinking of a global.asax equivalent location that I could place a log4net style writer with which to send caught errors.

What is the best way to catch errors globally in Xamarin apps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MonoTouch: uncaughtExceptionHandler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491813/monotouch-uncaughtexceptionhandler)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830510/monotouch-global-exception-handling and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491813/monotouch-uncaughtexceptionhandler